# Border color blending

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to ask you if anybody ever tried to achieve similar thing. Let's say I have a DOM structure consisting only of div elements, where there can be parents and children in only max 1 level. E.g

```
<div style="background-image:url(foo.bar)">
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-image:url(foo1.bar)">
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
    <div style="border:2px dashed black">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the difference between the backgrounds. Let's say the first one is a bright one and the second one very dark or black.

The struggle is to see the borders of the children on the dark background so the question would be.

Is there any possibility to make the border take some kind of negative color of it's parents background? Regardless if the parent has a picture or just a color as background. Some kind of multiply blending mode from ps?

I don't care if it is achievable with pure css (if even possible) or jquery plugin or some other sort of solution.

Thank you for any advices!

Comment: used solid or dashed only one not both

Comment: sorry that's fixed, my brain was probably off while typing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that you request (some blend mode) is achievable, but it is not supported in IE.

How to use it:

```css
.base { 
    width: 500px;
    height: 330px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 15%, red, green, yellow, white 80%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

.test {
   color: wheat;
   font-size: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 120px;
   top: 118px;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: dashed;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: this is great! And I don't really care about ie. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

To create a color inverted border use `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

```css
* {margin:0px; padding:0px; }

#border {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height:125px;

  border:10px solid white;
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekz0d.jpg" width="400">
<div id="border"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a semi-transparent color in your border and set the border to start from inside the content box.

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 362px;
    width: 465px;
    border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: url(http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/background-4.jpg) -20px -20px no-repeat;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>WooHoo!</div>
```

Comment: This is of course very nice example. But take black background and your border is invisible again. E.g. http://www.myokyawhtun.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Mandalay-in-bw.jpg and I don't know what the background will be, so it needs to be flexible somehow. But thank you!

Comment: @jPO I don't get it. How is your solution free from that problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's a blending color css option to use at backgrounds but it may be very difficult to adapt it to your borders as the background-image AND the property needs to be same container (which it's not your html).

The easiest way would be to use an RGBA color for your border:

```
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

Imo white at 50% transparency would make the trick... just a very, very light image would give you problems as in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/ybofg5d2/)**